# Add TIF image to Jlist or Frame in java

Tags: java, image, swing, tiff, jlist

i am trying to load a .TIF formatted image to add into Jlist and display it into frame.
Here is My code what i tried, here though the image is loaded my frame still looks empty and doesn't showing anything. 
please correct my code or suggest me that what should be the change i have to make display my .TIF image.

```
import javax.media.jai.PlanarImage;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ByteArraySeekableStream;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageCodec;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.SeekableStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class ImageViewer {
  static Image load(byte[] data) throws Exception {
    Image image = null;
    SeekableStream stream = new ByteArraySeekableStream(data);
    String[] names = ImageCodec.getDecoderNames(stream);
    ImageDecoder dec =
            ImageCodec.createImageDecoder(names[0], stream, null);
    RenderedImage im = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage();
    image = PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(im).getAsBufferedImage();
    return image;
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String path;

    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Split Pain");
    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    path ="C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/My Pictures/tiff Images/CCITT_1.TIF";
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
    FileChannel channel = in.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) channel.size());
    channel.read(buffer);
    Image image = load(buffer.array());
    Image imageScaled =image.getScaledInstance(500, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    listModel.addElement(new ImageIcon(imageScaled));
    final JList list = new JList(listModel);
    frame.add(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: as @Jakub already mentioned, tiff might not be supported as an image format - try to show it as icon in a plain label to verify

Comment: @GagandeepBali Sure.  But is is correctly installed, and more importantly, is the TIFF of a flavor of TIFF that JAI supports?  Most media formats are 'container formats' that might be encoded using a number of different compression techniques (CODECs).  There are instances of valid GIF, JPEG and PNG that J2SE does not support.  BTW - I doubt kleopatra was notified of your comment.  Best to add '@ name' (no space) unless the software is trying to stop you.

Comment: @kleopatra : The JAI package used by him does supports TIFF format :-)

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Dunno about the fact that is it installed properly or not, how much support this package has at present. How good a practise it is to use TIFF formats in Java though. I tried multiple thingies to sort things out but couldn't install it at my end. So cann't say much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlanarImage image = JAI.create("fileload", "C:\JAVA\mahes_24_m\09-11-1988\mdr16.tiff");
   using this syntax u can load tiff image. 
    BufferedImage bi = image.getAsBufferedImage();
 add this bi to ListModel and give this ListModel to JList, and add JList to JFrame.
but first u have to download JAI API to use PlanerImage Class.

Answer (score -1):

You need to supply your own `ListCellRenderer` implementation to the List:

```
class ImageIconCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer
{
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus){
        ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon)value;
        setIcon(icon);
        return this;
    }
}
```

and then in the main method:

```
list.setCellRenderer(new ImageIconCellRenderer());
```

But I am not sure tiff images are supported by standard Java.

Comment: -1 you don't need a custom list renderer to render icons, the default already does it

Comment: @Jakub Zaverka [Renderer knows following types of data in the list:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)